# .NET Maui - savedInstanceState is null when opening app via intent

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to use deeplink in .NET Maui.
but when i open it via chrome. An error is occurred as image
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiZmM.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Could you please the full error log about this problem?

Comment: According to the log you posted, I just find that there should be a problem with line 26 of class `MainActivity.cs `. How can we reproduce this problem? And could you please post the detailed steps?

Answer (score 0):

After I saw the image I can tell you your Theme is missing which could be the reason for this, set MainLauncher as true if that is your starting point:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true]
```

Comment: Hi, i try to do it on MainActivity like this, but still not work, do you have any other suggestions

Comment: Can you add the StackTrace of this to your question